# Should you submit player score and authenticate often?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm writing my first game. Every time the game is saved, I have it authenticate the local player and submit a highscore. Should I be authenticating and submitting scores often, or only when the score has changed?

Will GameCenter block incoming connections if I do this too many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only authenticate right when the app is opened. You should submit the score at the end of each game. For games that have a story, submit a score at the end of each level / section.

Games stay authenticated:

> After authenticating their account on a device, that player remains
>   connected on that device, even when the player switches to other
>   applications or reboots the device. A player only disconnects from
>   Game Center only by launching the Game Center application and
>   explicitly signing out.

Source: [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html)

Comment: What if it is still in memory and you reopen? Would it still be authenticated?

Comment: You only need to authenticate the first time you open the app. It stays authenticated.

Comment: Even if you lose connection?